# Converting 8 bytes of little-endian binary into a double precision float

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point, precision, endianness

I have a binary file that I read byte by byte.

I come across a section that is 8 bytes long, holding a double precision float (little endian). I can't figure out how to read this in and calculate it properly with masking and/or casting.

(To be specific, the file type is .LAS, but that shouldn't matter).

Are there any Java tricks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

from a `byte[] bytes`

```
 double d = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getDouble();
```

from a Socket

```
 ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(64*1024).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN );
 socket.read(bb);
 bb.flip();
 double d = bb.getDouble();
```

Comment: Extremely solid contribution, exactly what I needed. Thank you (and to everyone else who replied so fast!) Have a good weekend.

Comment: a direct buffer would be better here (2nd sample), provided the buffer it's not allocated often and reused. In such cases I tend to use the socket readBuffer as size.

Comment: @bestsss, Agreed that a direct ByteBuffer would be better if managed correctly.  I have found direct buffers can be up to 20% faster. If you use it with the Unsafe class it can be another 30% faster. ;)

Comment: non-direct (byte[] backed up) are actually copied from a ThreadLocal allocated ByteBuffer when read by a native file descriptor (socket/file)

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches are described here: http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/18253-big-endian-vs-little-endian-data. Both would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read and swap byte order, there is EndianUtils from Commons IO:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html

Comment: The link is broken (*"Not Found. The requested URL /proper/commons-io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html was not found on this server."*).

Comment: The link in the answer above is now working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert from little endian to big endian.
2. Wrap your converted bytes in `ByteBufferInputStream` use.
3. Get your double precision number via `DataInputStream.readDouble(in)`.

Alternatively, you can just take the body of the `readDouble` method from JDK source and skip step 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read the file, and use the `readDouble()` method.

Comment: DataInputStream is always "network ordered" which is big endian.

Comment: "An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream". I don't think that's the case here