# Efficient alternative to Outer on sparse arrays in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, outer-join, sparse-array

Suppose I have two very large lists {a1, a2, …} and {b1, b2, …} where all ai and bj are large sparse arrays. For the sake of memory efficiency I store each list as one comprehensive sparse array.

Now I would like to compute some function f on all possible pairs of ai and bj where each result f[ai, bj] is a sparse array again. All these sparse arrays have the same dimensions, by the way.

While

```
Flatten[Outer[f, {a1, a2, ...}, {b1, b2, ...}, 1], 1]
```

returns the desired result (in principle) it appears to consume excessive amounts of memory. Not the least because the return value is a list of sparse arrays whereas one comprehensive sparse array turns out much more efficient in my cases of interest.

Is there an efficient alternative to the above use of `Outer`?

More specific example:

```
{SparseArray[{{1, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2, 2, 2} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 1, 1, 2} -> 1, {2, 2, 2, 1} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 1, 2, 1} -> 1, {2, 2, 1, 2} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 1, 2, 2} -> -1, {2, 2, 1, 1} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 2, 1, 1} -> 1, {2, 1, 2, 2} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 2, 1, 2} -> 1, {2, 1, 2, 1} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 2, 2, 1} -> -1, {2, 1, 1, 2} -> 1}],
 SparseArray[{{1, 2, 2, 2} -> 1, {2, 1, 1, 1} -> 1}]};
ByteCount[%]

list = SparseArray[%%]
ByteCount[%]

Flatten[Outer[Dot, list, list, 1], 1];
ByteCount[%]
list1x2 = SparseArray[%%]
ByteCount[%]

Flatten[Outer[Dot, list1x2, list, 1], 1];
ByteCount[%]
list1x3 = SparseArray[%%]
ByteCount[%]
```

etc. Not only are the raw intermediate results of `Outer` (lists of sparse arrays) extremely inefficient, `Outer` seems to consume way too much memory during the computation itself, too.

Comment: You could have made a small self contained example to illustrate your problem. Because anyone who would answer you had to do that. see http://sscce.org/.  Is his the type of example you have? len = 1000; f[x_] := SparseArray[Table[x^2, {len}]]; list1 = SparseArray[Table[RandomReal[], {len}]]; list2 = SparseArray[Table[RandomReal[], {len}]]; Timing[Outer[f, list1, list2]][[1]]

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you mean with the phrase "comprehensive sparse array".  Could you try to elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @Nasser Shouldn't the function f in your example be one with two arguments?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I am sure you are might be correct, but that is the point of me asking. I was not sure about the question. If the user posts a small concrete example, then those who answer do not have to make up something and may be miss something in the process.

Comment: Just some thoughts here: `Outer` seems to have special support for `Times`: it keep the sparse structure and it's efficient.  Generally, `Outer[f, ...]` could be made much more efficient for sparse arrays if it could be guaranteed that the `f` function has no side effects (and as a result `f[a,b]` *always* returns the same result for the same `a` and `b`).  Then the "unspecified element" (usually 0) of the sparse array could be passed to `f` only once, and the result could be used as the new "unspecified element" in the new sparse array.  While it can't be detected automatically that some ...

Comment: ... function `f` has no side effects, `Outer` could have an option where we explicitly tell it that it can make this assumption.  Take this little comment as my suggested improvement to `Outer` :-)

Comment: Not sure whether it is directly relevant for your suggestion, but the function `f[a, b]` will actually not have the leaves of the sparse array `list` as arguments but rather the elements at the first level, i.e. sparse subarrays. I merely collect these subarrays into an overall sparse array (rather than a list) to reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 5):

I will propose a solution which is rather complex but allows one to only use about twice as much memory *during* the computation as is needed to store the final result as a `SparseArray`. The price to pay for this will be a much slower execution.

### The code

#### Sparse array construction / deconstruction API

Here is the code. First, a slightly modified (to address higher-dimensional sparse arrays) sparse array construction - deconstruction API, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064):

```
ClearAll[spart, getIC, getJR, getSparseData, getDefaultElement, 
  makeSparseArray];
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[s___], p_]] := {s}[[p]];
getIC[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[2, 1]];
getJR[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[2, 2]];
getSparseData[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[3]];
getDefaultElement[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 3];
makeSparseArray[dims_List, jc_List, ir_List, data_List, defElem_: 0] :=
   SparseArray @@ {Automatic, dims, defElem, {1, {jc, ir}, data}};
```

#### Iterators

The following functions produce iterators. Iterators are a good way to encapsulate the iteration process.

```
ClearAll[makeTwoListIterator];
makeTwoListIterator[fname_Symbol, a_List, b_List] :=
  With[{indices = Flatten[Outer[List, a, b, 1], 1]},
   With[{len  = Length[indices]},
    Module[{i = 0},
      ClearAll[fname];
      fname[] := With[{ind = ++i}, indices[[ind]] /; ind <= len];
      fname[] := Null;
      fname[n_] := 
        With[{ind = i + 1}, i += n; 
           indices[[ind ;; Min[len, ind + n - 1]]] /; ind <= len];
      fname[n_] := Null;
 ]]];
```

Note that I could have implemented the above function more memory - efficiently and not use `Outer` in it, but for our purposes this won't be the major concern.

Here is a more specialized version, which produces interators for pairs of 2-dimensional indices.

```
ClearAll[make2DIndexInterator];
make2DIndexInterator[fname_Symbol, i : {iStart_, iEnd_}, j : {jStart_, jEnd_}] :=
   makeTwoListIterator[fname, Range @@ i, Range @@ j];
 make2DIndexInterator[fname_Symbol, ilen_Integer, jlen_Integer] :=
   make2DIndexInterator[fname, {1, ilen}, {1, jlen}];
```

Here is how this works:

```
In[14]:= 
makeTwoListIterator[next,{a,b,c},{d,e}];
next[]
next[]
next[]

Out[15]= {a,d}
Out[16]= {a,e}
Out[17]= {b,d}
```

We can also use this to get batch results:

```
In[18]:= 
makeTwoListIterator[next,{a,b,c},{d,e}];
next[2]
next[2]

Out[19]= {{a,d},{a,e}}
Out[20]= {{b,d},{b,e}}
```

, and we will be using this second form.

#### SparseArray - building function

This function will build a `SparseArray` object iteratively, by getting chunks of data (also in `SparseArray` form) and gluing them together. It is basically code used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064) answer, packaged into a function. It accepts the code piece used to produce the next chunk of data, wrapped in `Hold` (I could alternatively make it `HoldAll`)

```
Clear[accumulateSparseArray];
accumulateSparseArray[Hold[getDataChunkCode_]] :=
  Module[{start, ic, jr, sparseData, dims, dataChunk},
   start = getDataChunkCode;
   ic = getIC[start];
   jr = getJR[start];
   sparseData = getSparseData[start];
   dims = Dimensions[start];
   While[True, dataChunk = getDataChunkCode;
     If[dataChunk === {}, Break[]];
     ic = Join[ic, Rest@getIC[dataChunk] + Last@ic];
     jr = Join[jr, getJR[dataChunk]];
     sparseData = Join[sparseData, getSparseData[dataChunk]];
     dims[[1]] += First[Dimensions[dataChunk]];
   ];
   makeSparseArray[dims, ic, jr, sparseData]];
```

#### Putting it all together

This function is the main one, putting it all together:

```
ClearAll[sparseArrayOuter];
sparseArrayOuter[f_, a_SparseArray, b_SparseArray, chunkSize_: 100] := 
  Module[{next, wrapperF, getDataChunkCode},
    make2DIndexInterator[next, Length@a, Length@b];
    wrapperF[x_List, y_List] := SparseArray[f @@@ Transpose[{x, y}]];
    getDataChunkCode :=
      With[{inds = next[chunkSize]},
         If[inds === Null, Return[{}]];
         wrapperF[a[[#]] & /@ inds[[All, 1]], b[[#]] & /@ inds[[All, -1]]]
      ];
    accumulateSparseArray[Hold[getDataChunkCode]]
  ];
```

Here, we first produce the iterator which will give us on demand portions of index pair list, used to extract the elements (also `SparseArrays`). Note that we will generally extract more than one pair of elements from two large input `SparseArray`-s at a time, to speed up the code. How many pairs we process at once is governed by the optional `chunkSize` parameter, which defaults to `100`. We then construct the code to process these elements and put the result back into `SparseArray`, where we use an auxiliary function `wrapperF`. The use of iterators wasn't absolutely necessary (could use `Reap`-`Sow` instead, as with other answers), but allowed me to decouple the logic of iteration from the logic  of generic accumulation of sparse arrays.

### Benchmarks

First we prepare large sparse arrays and test our functionality:

```
In[49]:= 
arr = {SparseArray[{{1,1,1,1}->1,{2,2,2,2}->1}],SparseArray[{{1,1,1,2}->1,{2,2,2,1}->1}],
SparseArray[{{1,1,2,1}->1,{2,2,1,2}->1}],SparseArray[{{1,1,2,2}->-1,{2,2,1,1}->1}],
SparseArray[{{1,2,1,1}->1,{2,1,2,2}->1}],SparseArray[{{1,2,1,2}->1,{2,1,2,1}->1}]};

In[50]:= list=SparseArray[arr]
Out[50]= SparseArray[<12>,{6,2,2,2,2}]

In[51]:= larger = sparseArrayOuter[Dot,list,list]
Out[51]= SparseArray[<72>,{36,2,2,2,2,2,2}]

In[52]:= (large= sparseArrayOuter[Dot,larger,larger])//Timing
Out[52]= {0.047,SparseArray[<2592>,{1296,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}]}

In[53]:= SparseArray[Flatten[Outer[Dot,larger,larger,1],1]]==large
Out[53]= True

In[54]:= MaxMemoryUsed[]
Out[54]= 21347336
```

Now we do the power tests

```
In[55]:= (huge= sparseArrayOuter[Dot,large,large,2000])//Timing
Out[55]= {114.344,SparseArray[<3359232>,{1679616,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}]}

In[56]:= MaxMemoryUsed[]
Out[56]= 536941120

In[57]:= ByteCount[huge]
Out[57]= 262021120

In[58]:= (huge1 = Flatten[Outer[Dot,large,large,1],1]);//Timing
Out[58]= {8.687,Null}

In[59]:= MaxMemoryUsed[]
Out[59]= 2527281392
```

For this particular example, the suggested method is 5 times more memory-efficient than the direct use of `Outer`, but about 15 times slower. I had to tweak the `chunksize` parameter (default is `100`, but for the above I used `2000`, to get the optimal speed / memory use combination). My method only used as a peak value twice as much memory as needed to store the final result. The degree of memory-savings as compared to `Outer`- based method will depend on the sparse arrays in question.

Comment: I am not voting until I have time to test and understand this, but I was hoping you'd reply.

Answer (score 0):

If `lst1` and `lst2` are your lists,

```
Reap[
   Do[Sow[f[#1[[i]], #2[[j]]]],
       {i, 1, Length@#1},
       {j, 1, Length@#2}
       ] &[lst1, lst2];
   ] // Last // Last
```

does the job and may be more memory-efficient. On the other hand, maybe not. Nasser is right, an explicit example would be useful.

EDIT: Using Nasser's randomly-generated arrays, and for `len=200`, `MaxMemoryUsed[]` indicates that this form needs 170MB while the `Outer` form in the question takes 435MB.

Comment: How about: Reap[Do[Sow[Dot[i, j]], {i, r}, {j, r}];] // Last // Last  with r={SparseArray[],..} or Flatten[Table[Dot[i, j], {i, r}, {j, r}], 1]

Answer (score 0):

Using your example `list` data, I believe that you will find the ability to `Append` to a `SparseArray` quite helpful.

```
acc = SparseArray[{}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]

Do[AppendTo[acc, i.j], {i, list}, {j, list}]

Rest[acc]
```

I need `Rest` to drop the first zero-filled tensor in the result.  The second argument of the seed `SparseArray` must be the dimensions of each of your elements with a prefixed `1`.  You may need to explicitly specify a background for the seed `SparseArray` to optimize performance.

Comment: You could use Internal`Bag stuff, depending how many of those arrays you have.

Comment: @ruebenko, how does that compare to appending directly to the `SparseArray`?

Comment: in fact it does not; Suffing Bag with SparseArray makes a Normal of the SA. I did not know that. This at least explains why Internal`Bag is only internal. It is not fully implemented for arbitrary exprs.

Comment: Using `acc = SparseArray[{}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]; Do[AppendTo[acc, Dot[i, j]], {i, list}, {j, list}]; list1x2 = Rest[acc]; Clear[acc]` etc. I get much worse performance in fact. For one thing, the sparse arrays `list1x2`, `list1x3` etc. occupy more memory than their counterparts constructed via `Outer` above although a test reveals they are equal. Also, by the time `list1x6` is being calculated the MathKernel runs out of memory while this does not happen with the `Outer`approach. Any idea as to why is that?

Comment: @groovybaby please try this and report: `Do[AppendTo[acc, list[[i]].list[[j]]], {i, Length@list}, {j, Length@list}]`  I think `Do` was un-sparse-ing the elements.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Tried this and it appears to be ridiculously efficient on memory… at the expense of a very slow runtime though. Well, I guess there always is a tradeoff one way or the other. Thanks for your hint!